# Return the Task Result from Data Flow Task to Script Component

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I created an SSIS package where i am loading Multiple Flat Files to my database Table.

[image]

As you can see, i have used For Each Loop to Loop through Multiple Files, and inside ForEach loop i've used Data Flow Task which is going to take care of Loading Files to Table and Later i'm Storing the Loaded and Failed files name in Log file and Only Renaming those Loaded files.

Everything is working great, but as you can see, i have used 2 script Task to perform a small operation which can be done using a Single Script Task by Setting the Precedence Constraint to "Complete" instead of "Success" on Data Flow Task. But my problem is, how can i fetch the Data Flow Task Result in Script Task i.e., how to check whether Data Flow Task has Failed or Success in Script Task.

[image]

Here is my Script Code where i'm Logging the File Name and Renaming based on the Task Result from Data Flow Task.

```
    public void Main()
    {
        bool DataFlowTaskResult = false;//setting true or False based on Result from Data Flow Task

        if (DataFlowTaskResult)
        {
            Dts.Events.FireError(0, null, Dts.Variables["User::FileName"].Value.ToString() + " " + "Inserted Succefully", string.Empty, 0);
        }
        else
        {
            Dts.Events.FireError(0, null, Dts.Variables["User::FileName"].Value.ToString() + " " + "Inserted Succefully", string.Empty, 0);
        }
        Dts.TaskResult = (DataFlowTaskResult) ? (int)ScriptResults.Success : (int)ScriptResults.Failure;    
    }
```

Comment: If it's available at all, it might be in the Post Execute event handler, but I think you're going to need to use Precedence Constraints like you were before.

Comment: You got me curious so I did some searching and testing but I could not find a way.  The script task is basically unaware of other tasks which makes since.  however, there are still other ways of doing it but not sure they are easier than maintaining the two script tasks. 1 is create a variable and use Execute SQL or Script tasks to set the value of that variable based on success or failure than map that to this task.  2 there might be a way with a parent child package configuration too

Comment: Thanks Tab and Matt, even i thought the same of using a Boolean variable to set True or False in Precedence Constraint of Data Flow Task and accessing that value in my script task. But that is not what i wanted actually. Well i'll leave this qiuestion in a hope that some one may find a better way to do it.